# How to find time complexity of this program?

Tags: haskell

I have a data list.

```
db = [("Ada","works", "IBM")
  ,("Alice","director", "Ada")
  ,("Tom","works", "IBM")
  ,("Tommy","director", "Tom")
 ,("IBM","isat",     "CA")
 ,("CA","in",       "USA")
 ]
ask db = map (\(x,y,z) -> (z == "IBM")) db
```

How to calculate the complexity of O(n)？
If I want to get the result by the length of list 2,5,10.O(n) is same like 2,5,10?And If I do

```
trans2 db = concat (map ((x,y,z) -> concat (map((x',y',z') -> if (z==x') then [] else [(x,y ++ "." ++ y',z')] else []) db)) db )
```

How can I calculate the O(n)? The runtime of program? The timming complexity

Comment: The complexity of *O(n)*?? *O(n)* is a complexity class.

Comment: the function O(n) time complexity

Comment: The comparison is a constant time operation done `n` times (because of your use of `map`), so the `ask` function runs in O(n) (aka linear time).

Comment: Yea,but how could I get  it? I am the beginner,I did not konw how to get the complexity.If I have O(n),O(n2)and O(n5).

Comment: what do you mean by "code for it"?

Comment: btw: are you sure you want `map`? seems like a job for `filter` (does not change the complexity though)

Comment: To write the code in Haskell to get the result and the graph

Comment: Yea it's filter

Comment: you can see it like this: `map`  will look at every element in the list - if the *looking* takes constant time `c` and you have `n` elements you get `n*c` time - and since you usually want complexity as a function of the length of the list you have `O(n)` here (just look up the definition - it's trivial in this case)

Comment: oh - you want some kind of experiment? For small lists like this you cannot really measure runtime in a meaningful way

Comment: Yea,but if I only want to get the result by the length of list 2,5,10.O(n) is same like 2,5,10?And If I do trans2 db = concat (map (\(x,y,z) -> concat (map(\(x',y',z') -> if (z==x') then [] else [(x,y ++ "." ++ y',z')] else []) db)) db )    How can I calculate the O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear and I expect it will soon be closed.  Briefly.

O(n) *is* a complexity.  If you know O(n) and you wanted complexity then you're done.

The length of the list (2, 5, 10, what have you) is not a factor in the complexity in this case since the length is what the `n` is representing.

There is no code that will calculate the complexity of the algorithm automatically.  It is a manual analysis.

Comment: It's means that if there are 5 sublists in db,the complexity is 5? However, if I take the other operation such as inverse the list and combine with the others ,how can I calculate the complexity?TKS.

Comment: No, because `5` is not a complexity class.  You keep trying to reduce the answer to a single number, which is itself a misunderstanding.

Comment: It means that the time complexity is depend on the length of list.